# convert biginteger to hex String? throws exception, why?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, biginteger

I'm trying to convert the number inside the `publickey` variable array to `Hex` number. the code `HEX_key = Hex(publickey(0))` is throwing an error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Argument 'Number' cannot be converted to type 'BigInteger'.'

How do I rectify this? How do I convert a BigInteger to a hex string?

`public key is "-31969172801463260124234214026687674925736772420938592197321821673909885626448"`

```
Private Sub Button14_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button14.Click

     Dim publickey() As BigInteger
    Dim HEX_key As String = Nothing
    publickey = EccMultiply(GENPOINT, Privatekey)
    HEX_key = Hex(publickey(0))
    TextBox11.Text = HEX_key

End Sub
```

**P.S:** `EccMultiply()` is a function which gives the value `"-31969172801463260124234214026687674925736772420938592197321821673909885626448"` which I have mentioned above, the publickey variable has that value now, so `publickey = (that big number)`. `Function EccMultiply(genpoint, ScalarHex)`. I didn't include the function code here as it will make the code long. and `Hex()` is `"Imports System.Numerics"`

Comment: Show at least the declarations for `EccMultiply()` and `Hex()`

Comment: EccMultiply() is a function which gives the value `"-31969172801463260124234214026687674925736772420938592197321821673909885626448"` which I have mentioned above, the `publickey` variable has that value now, so `publickey = (that big number)`. `Function EccMultiply(genpoint, ScalarHex)`. I didn't include the function code here as it will make the code long. and `Hex()` is `"Imports System.Numerics"`

Comment: **edit the question** to include that info. It's not helpful trying to read it with the limited comment formatting. At minimum, I see `EccMultiply()` does not specify a return type, which is a major error.

Comment: what do you mean by return type like `Function EccMultiply(genpoint, ScalarHex) As BigInteger() `? I added that to the function and it doesn't change the exception.

Comment: yes, but why the parenthese? They indicate an array, and it doesn't seem like you're working with arrays here. Is it possible you need to set `Option Strict On`?

Comment: (I mean :) `dim big = BigInteger.Parse("-31969172801463260124234214026687674925736772420938592197321821673909885626448") dim hex as string = big.ToString("X2")`

Comment: @Jimi : ultimately you have to use `Dim big = BigInteger.Parse(publickey(0))` instead of string version of that number, that's where the same exception is raised. the problem is not `numerical String to hex string` the problem is `biginteger to hex string`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn : `EccMultiply` does outputs an array, so that's the reason to use `()`, and yes option strict is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the error message. It's not telling you that the argument is a value that cannot be converted to a `BigInteger` value. It is telling you that `Hex` doesn't support the `BigInteger` type. The documentation states that the overload with an `Object` parameter accepts *"Any valid numeric expression or String expression"* but that means any of the standard numeric types. `Hex` doesn't underdstand `BigInteger`. I think that your best option is to convert the `BigInteger` to a `Byte` array and then convert to hexadecimal yourself.

Here is an extension method that will convert a `BigInteger` to a hexadecimal `String`:

```vb
Imports System.Numerics
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module BigIntegerExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function ToHexadecimal(source As BigInteger) As String
        Dim data = source.ToByteArray()

        Return String.Concat(data.Reverse().Select(Function(b) b.ToString("X2")))
    End Function

End Module
```

Here's some sample usage:

```vb
Imports System.Numerics

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim n = 123456789
        Dim b = New BigInteger(n)

        Console.WriteLine(n.ToString("X"))
        Console.WriteLine(b.ToHexadecimal())

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

You'll notice that, in that example, the second output has a leading "0" that the first output lacks. That's because each `Byte` is converted to two hex digits so the output will always have an even number of digits. If you don't want that then you can either call `TrimStart` on the output or you can treat the highest-order byte differently:

```vb
Imports System.Numerics
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module BigIntegerExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function ToHexadecimal(source As BigInteger) As String
        Dim data = source.ToByteArray()

        Array.Reverse(data)

        Return String.Concat(data.Skip(1).
                                  Select(Function(b) b.ToString("X2")).
                                  Prepend(data(0).ToString("X")))
    End Function

End Module
```